# Is there a shift and copy cpu instruction that can be accessed from c#?

Tags: c#, assembly

I need to take an 8 bit number on a 64 bit cpu and shift it to the right 8 times. Each time I shift the number I need to shift the same 8 bit number in behind it so that I end up with the same 8 bit number repeating 8 times. This would end up being shift, add 8, shift add 8... etc. which ends up being 40+ cycles (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there a way to do this operation (of shift and copy) in 1 cycle so that I end up with the same value in the end?

```
long _value = 0;
byte _number = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    _value = (_value << 8) + _number;
}
```

EDIT: I'm trying to compare a stream of chars to detect keywords. I can't use string.contains because the string value may be across the boundary of the buffer. Also, the application has to run on embedded ARM cpus as well as desktop and server CPUs. Memory usage and cpu cycles are very important.

Comment: I don't think this kind of function exists. C# is a high level language. If you need these kind of optimizations, use a low level language like C.

Comment: @Chris Unsafe allows you to use pointer not to use new instructions.

Comment: "ends up being 40+ cycles" - x86/x64 cycles are as virtual as MSIL. Very hard to predict how this will work out in pipelined RISC instructions.

Comment: Is that really faster than _value * 0x101010101010101? I'd hope the hardware multiply would be efficient here.

Comment: @Rup, I was thinking about using some sort of multiply instruction but I just don't know the math :( How did you arrive at "101010101010101"?

Comment: @Rup: `_value * 0x101010101010101 = 0`

Comment: So it's a toss up between this and lookup tables.

Comment: @leppie OK, I meant `_number * 0x101010101010101` which does give the same answer.

Comment: @kurtnelle it's 10101... because that's the first bit set on each of eight bytes - or put a different way it's the result of `_number = 1` and you can get the result for any other `_number` by multiplying up. But you're right, lookup tables are a good idea too.

Comment: @Rup: I'll add some timing for that too, once I get home (so the results are comparable) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another idea would be to precompute all for all values of byte a lookup table.

```
var lu = new long[256];
// init
var n = 7;
var v = lu[n];
```

**Update**

Some benchmark results (in ms per 100000000 iterations):

- Loop: 272
- Unrolled: 207
- Unsafe: 351
- Lookup: 250
- HenkH: 216

The unrolled version is:

```
long _value = 0;
byte _number = 7;

_value = (_value + _number) << 8;
_value = (_value + _number) << 8;
_value = (_value + _number) << 8;
_value = (_value + _number) << 8;
_value = (_value + _number) << 8;
_value = (_value + _number) << 8;
_value = (_value + _number) << 8;
_value = (_value + _number) << 8;
```

The unsafe version is:

```
long _value = 0;
byte _number = 7;

byte* p = (byte*)&_value;

*p++ = _number;
*p++ = _number;
*p++ = _number;
*p++ = _number;
*p++ = _number;
*p++ = _number;
*p++ = _number;
*p++ = _number;
```

Sadly not performing :(

The lookup is just a read to an array.

All compiled for x64/release.

Comment: At least 1 thing is confirmed: You can't tell from just looking at the code ):

Comment: Leppie, there are a few tweaks you might try: `long` should have been `ulong` all along I wonder if `|` instead of `+` would be noticeable.

Comment: Won't the lookup process for the array end up taking longer? Unless it's a binary tree lookup it may perform worse than the loop?

Comment: @kurtnelle: You would have to initialize the table, but with it being so small, it would hardly take time. Also, you can just fill it with constants. And I did give the timing based on getting a value from that initialized array.

Comment: Since there are only 265 items in the array it should be best to pre compute and look up.

Comment: @kurtn: strangely enough the benchmarks say it's not. I would have guessed them fastest too.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays, there is no direct connection between number of **instructions** performed and the number of **cpu cycles** which are needed to execute them.
You also seem to assume that a **statement** in C# corresponds to a single assembly/cpu instruction which also is wrong.

Your code seem correctly do what your algorithm description says (note that long is signed, use **ulong** for unsigned behaviour).

If you want to use specialized **cpu extensions** (like mmx,sse,whatever) that can do add-shift-assignment in one instruction, you need to use assembly code. But I am not sure if such a specific  instruction exist. This may depend on the type of CPU you have.

You cannot use assembly code directly together with c#, but you can use assembly together with **c** (either as linked object file use make it inline assembly). The compiled c-code can be used from c#/.net with **interop**.

But the first and important question for you should be: **What are you trying to accomplish?**

I doubt that performance is this critical for your app, and even if, you should honestly ask yourself if c# is the best language for your goal.

Comment: @codymainx: There are a few places in the proposed algorithm that I;m trying to optimize. Since this is intended to work in long running application, any performance gain (without to much developer overhead) would be a plus.

Answer (score 3):

When you want it to be fast you could at least unroll your loop:

```
ulong _value = 0;
byte _number = 7;

_value = _number;
_value = (_value <<  8) + _value;
_value = (_value << 16) + _value;
_value = (_value << 32) + _value;
```

This would have fewer branches too.

Comment: This is not the faster: you should write just one expression. The MSIL will compose the formula as RPN, avoiding several (useless) operations.

Comment: I was under the impression that the compiler / jit did a lot of things like this for you. It makes sense in this case, but I hesitate to arbitrarily unroll loops for 'performance' reasons. Its worth a try, but I would definitely benchmark it to see the actual performance gain.

Comment: The main point was using the intermediates to reduce the number of steps. I would expect/hope that the Jitter would optimize these statements as a group, otherwise @Mario is right. I would not expect the Jitter to reduce it from 8 to 4 steps.

Comment: My apologize for writing "faster" instead of "fastest".
I made some benchmarking (nothing serious though), and it is much faster. The inline formula appears to be the fastest.
I agree that the result may change on other platforms.
I wonder why the guy is looking for such a strange thing, though...

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Added benchmarks to my answer, yours comes close to the 'naive' unrolled version.

Comment: I thought about unrolling the loop, but yes the performance gains are minimal.